# jquery on click event only fire once

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I understand based on countless research on other stackexchange questions with similar problems that the event instance gets undo after the onclick event however im not seeing any way to solve it. My problem is that when the radio button is clicked and the ajax is fired and returns the data i cant get it to fire again to retrieve the next row after the one just retrieved. Im making a quiz webapp and when user clicks on right radio button it submit ajax request to get next question and next set of options. only the data changes the radio buttons remain the same only the dom data changes.

here is the ajax:

```
<script>  
 $(document).ready(function(){  
      $(document).on("change", ":radio", function(){  
           var answer = $('input[type="radio"]:checked').val();
           var question_id = $('#dataContainer').data('value');  
           $.ajax({  
                url:"quizengine.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:{
                    answer:answer,
                    question_id:question_id
                },
                dataType: 'json',  
                success:function(response){ 
                    $('input[type="radio"]').prop('checked', false);
                    var num = $('#dataContainer').data("value") + response[5]; 
                    console.log(response);
                    $('#instruction').html(response[0]);
                    $('#question').replaceWith(response[1]);
                    $('#answer_one').html(response[2]);
                    $('#answer_two').html(response[3]);
                    $('#answer_three').html(response[4]);
                    $('#dataContainer').attr("data-value",num);  
                }  
           });

      });  
 });  
 </script> 

and here is the php that goes with it:
<?php 

if (isset($_POST['answer'])) {
    global $connection;
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];
        $question_id = $_POST['question_id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT is_right FROM answers WHERE question_id='$question_id'");
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
        if (isset($row)) {
            $correct = $row['is_right'];
            if ($answer === $correct) {
                $next = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT Questions.question_id,Questions.lesson,Questions.instruction,Questions.question,Questions.image,Questions.option_type,Questions.question_value,Answers.answer_one,Answers.answer_two,Answers.answer_three,Answers.is_right FROM Questions LEFT JOIN Answers ON Questions.question_id = Answers.question_id WHERE Questions.question_id>'$question_id' ORDER BY Questions.question_id ASC LIMIT 1");

                $nextrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($next);
                $row_info = array($nextrow['instruction'],$nextrow['question'],$nextrow['answer_one'],$nextrow['answer_two'],$nextrow['answer_three'],$nextrow['question_id']);
                echo json_encode($row_info);
                exit();
            }else{
                echo "error";
                exit();
            }
        }

    }




?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you test if a 'fail' or 'done' callback is fired at the second time ?